# From a page, is it possible to find entry's "menu_item_parent"?

Tags: menus, filters, sub-menu

The idea would be to be able to retrieve a **sub-menu** matching a given page to display it as an aside on page.

As an exemple, let's consider this menu:

- Home
- Outdoor

  - MTB
  - Rock climbing
  - Running
  - Hiking
- Indoor

  - …
- About US
- Blog

So if I'm on the Hiking page I'd want to retrieve Outdoor and all of its sub-items. For this, I figure I would first need to get `menu_item_parent` and then filter all items from there.

Or is there a better solution? Currently, the only way I'm seeing is to use classes on all the menu items and filter based on these classes, not optimal…

Comment: Put a look here: https://christianvarga.com/how-to-get-submenu-items-from-a-wordpress-menu-based-on-parent-or-sibling/ This link help you ?

Comment: Looks like it would do the trick. I have yet to try it out. Went the "classes" path so far.